# Bash - looping through specified folders to find empty files

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, for

I want to `loop` through a set of folders, specified within the script and print all files that are empty. I use this script:

```
array=("folderA" "folderX")    

for file in ./"${array[@]}"/*; do

  if [ -s "${file}" ]; then

    echo "$file"

  fi
done
```

This does not work, I only get the output of the first folder specified in the array, like this:

```
./folderX
./folderA/emty_file1
./folderA/emty_file7
./folderA/emty_file12
./folderA/emty_file24
```

How can I make the script also detect empty files in the other directories specified in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to iterate,

```
array=("folderA" "folderX")
find "${array[@]}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -empty
```

Comment: **Ok,** you won the `Code Golfing`! **THX :-)** _(hope you don't mind the edit, just seemed like copy and paste error...)_

Answer (score 2):

An alternative simple solution:

```
for i in "folderA" "folderX"
  do find "$i" -type f -empty
done
```

Be sure to include a path with the folder name, like "/usr/local" if the script is started from a different location.

Edit:
Also, like pointed out correctly, if you want to limit the search scope use it with maxdepth accordingly:

```
for i in "folderA" "folderX"
  do find "$i" -maxdepth 1 -type f -empty
done
```

Comment: **Nice and easy THANKS** - For simplicity reasons I chose [roaimas answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/624489/240990).

Answer (score 1):

`./"${array[@]}"/*` expands to:

```
./folderA folderB/*
```

because the `./` goes to the beginning of the first element and the `/*` goes to the end of the second one.

What you need to do is to add /* each element of the array to add the suffix:

```
"${array[@]/%//*}"
```

You can search for ${var/%Pattern/Replacement} [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) for more info and to see how to also add "./" to the beginning (though for your particular case the above substitution is enough).

Comment: adding the glob `*` to all array elements like `array=("folderA/*" "folderX/*")` does not make my loop work... **THX** for the link with the [parameter substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)!

Answer (score 1):

**May be this will help you to get the expected result**

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=("folderA" "folderX")    # Storing folder names to an array 
arr_count=${#arr[@]}     # Stroing count of element's in an array 
echo "Count of array :  $arr_count" # Printing the count of elements present in an array 

for ((  i=0 ; i<2 ; i++ ))
{
   find "$(pwd)"/"${arr[$i]}" -empty -type f 
}
```

If you want to delete those empty file just add this `-delete` to above find command

```
find "$(pwd)"/"${arr[$i]}" -empty -type f -delete
```

Comment: Not the simplest solution, but definitely working, **THX!**